# Call to undefined function hash_equals() in Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the basic info from the facebook user. I'm following official docs. I don't know how to get rid of this error.

```
session_start();
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXX', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

//Get the Access Token

try {
        //access token for the account
        $access_token=$helper->getAccessToken();

} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an erorr'. $e->getMessage();
        exit;
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an erorr'. $e->getMessage();
        exit;
}

echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());


$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://startup-sarathjasrin.c9users.io/login/');

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

I'm using latest facebook-php-sdk-v5.

Answer (score 4):

The error says the function function hash_equals() does not exist. This is a php built in hashing system available only for:

> (PHP 5 >= 5.6.0)

So if you have a version older than 5.6.0 you will not have this function built in. Reading the documentation: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php)

on a side note you are able able to create your own hash_equals function:

```
if(!function_exists('hash_equals'))
{
    function hash_equals($str1, $str2)
    {
        if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
            $ret = 0;
            for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
            }
            return !$ret;
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively download the compatibility package from git [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) however this package is for the newer php hashing and will require some code rework as it uses password_verify rather than hash_equals

Comment: This function is not available in Google AppEngine as well, so Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook PHP SDK Developers already included a polyfill for that:
[https://github.com/facebook/.../polyfills.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/polyfills.php)

So you should only inlude this file in your script;
for instance:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Facebook'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'polyfills.php');
```

Creating your own hash_equals function may cause an unpredictible behaviour, because polyfills.php implementation is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/polyfills.php';
```

where the error was generated: /SignedRequest.php

Comment: If you are using symfony you can add polyfills file to the framework autoload. Works too